# How can I get the first 10 digits from EditText, and set this digits in a TextView?

Tags: java, android, character

I have a field filled with an EditText control, it figures: `475759403048575663648495004945757590`.

What can I use to choose the first 10 numbers from this EditText:

 and then, insert the numbers `4757594030`, in the TextView?

Answer (score 3):

You can substring the string to 10 characters.

```
String s = somestring.substring(0,10);
```

So this will return the first 10 characters, and now you can put the value S in your control!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a textwatcher to the edittext, then count as the edit text is being edited, when you get to the number of characters (10 in this case), you can then display those characters.

Example

```
TextView textView = ....
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable textVal) {
        String inputText = textVal.toString();
        if (inputText.length() == 10) {
             textView.setText(inputText);
        }
    }
});
```