# How delete first 10 characters in String?

Tags: java, string

I have an array of string, it apron random figures, for example:"`475759403048575663648495004945757590`" . How can I remove the first 10 digits ?

Comment: where is the `array` ?

Comment: Read the documentation or do some research online.  This is a Java question, not an Android question.  [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: why not use `substring` metod of `String class`

Comment: dude u asked the same thing yesterday and I didn't get any feedback at all..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22143547/3239917

Answer (score 6):

You can use `substring()` method from [Java's String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class like below code,

```
String str = "475759403048575663648495004945757590"
str = str.substring(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method of [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class :

```
String removeSubString = "475759403048575663648495004945757590"
   removeSubString = removeString.substring(10);
```

Comment: `getText()` *doesn't* return a string?

Comment: `getText()` is used to get Text data from  `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [substring(int beginIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method of String class which
returns a new string that is a substring of this string.

```
   String str="4785214522396554786324";
   str=str.substring(10);
```

It will form String starting from 10th index till end of String.